# Multi server installation using autospinstaller

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, autospinstaller

I am trying to install in a farm which has 1 app server which hosts the central admin server and 1 wfe and 1 search server.
I have added server name in provision tag depends on which service to run on which server.
I have also enabled remoting in all the servers.
Now do i need to run the script from each of the server or the autospinstaller will install on all the server.

Thanks,
Sudan

Answer (score 4):

You only have to run the AutoSPInstaller script from a single server. It will go out and run itself on all other servers in your farm. Be sure to enable autologon in your XML file. The first server will install itself, create the farm and the service applications and in the end connect to the other servers.

Very important is that you start the script on the server via a UNC path \\server\folder\autospinstaller.bat and not directly c:\folder\autospinstaller.bat

Comment: thanks for the quick response.it installs the binary on first server and asks me to proceed with farm configuration.so will it install on the other server only after this step?

Comment: Just click yes, it will configure the farm and the service applications. At the end of that process he will start to install binaries and activate services on the other servers.

Comment: When the installation starts on the remote server i am receiving an error version v4.0.030319 of the .net framework is not installed and it is required to un version 3 of windows powershell.   If i manually install the .netframe work the auto installer says the .net frmework is alreday installed and stuck on "running pre req installer in offlinemode" and does not move.